# Живой поиск в определенном блоке

Tags: javascript, html

Нашел вот этот код на [codepen](https://codepen.io/shahjehan/pen/NGWaKq)

Ищет по значениям  `<li> и <ul>`  тегов. Всё отлично. Но у меня и меню и боковая панель состоит из ul и li. Хотелось бы чтоб этот код как то искал только по определенному блоку т е при поиске не действовал на меню. Например боковая панель находится внутри тега `<div class="1page-sidebar">` , как обьяснить вышеприведенному коду чтоб он "смотрел" только на эту панель.

```
`<div class="1page-sidebar">
            <!-- START X-NAVIGATION -->
            <ul class="x-navigation">


                <form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <h1>Поиск</h1>
    <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" placeholder="Живой поиск" />
    <span id="filter-count"></span>
</fieldset>
```

`

```
<a href="#"> <span 
class="fa fa-desktop"></span> <span class="xn-text">    Справочник</span></a>                        
                </li> 
                <li class="xn-openable">
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-file-text-o"></span> 
<span class="xn-text">    Терапия</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="xn-openable"><a href="">Некариозные поражения твердых тканей зубов</a>
                        <ul>


                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('jaloby').value = 'Жалобы на косметический дефект и чувствительность ... зубов!' ; document.getElementById('obekt').value = 'На вестибулярной поверхности зубов наблюдается поражение эмали. Поверхность блестящая, гладкая и твердая при зондировании. Зондирование и реакция на температурный раздражитель чувствительная, перкуссия' ; document.getElementById('diagnoz').value = 'эрозия эмали КОЗ.2 (МКБ-10)'">Эрозия эмали</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('jaloby').value = 'Жалобы на косметический дефект в области ... зубов' ; document.getElementById('obekt').value = 'На вестибулярной поверхности зубов блестящие белые пятна на фоне плотной эмали, безболезненные при зондировании, не окрашивающиеся индикатором кариеса ' ; document.getElementById('diagnoz').value = 'флюороз К00.3 (МКБ-10)'">Флюороз</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('jaloby').value = 'На изменений пропорций лица, боли в ВНЧС снижение высоты коронок, косметические изменение и чувствительность зубов' ; document.getElementById('obekt').value = 'В группе зубов наблюдается стертость клинических коронок. За счет этого снижена высота прикуса. Зондирование и реакция на температурный раздражитель болезненная, перкуссия ' ; document.getElementById('diagnoz').value = 'патологическая стираемость К03.0 (МКБ-10)'">патологическая стираемость</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('jaloby').value = 'На косметический дефект' ; document.getElementById('obekt').value = '' ; document.getElementById('diagnoz').value = 'некроз эмали'">некроз эмали</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('jaloby').value = 'Жалобы на косметический дефект и чувствительность от механических и химических раздражителей' ; document.getElementById('obekt').value = 'В пришеечной области зуба дефект твердых тканей в виде клина. Зондирование дефекта безболезненно, перкуссия, термометрия гипоплазия эмали' ; document.getElementById('diagnoz').value = 'клиновидный дефект К03.10 (МКБ-10)'">клиновидный дефект</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('jaloby').value = 'На косметический дефект ... зубов' ; document.getElementById('obekt').value = 'На поверхности группы зубов изменение цвета эмали, формы и величины. Поверхность эмали гладкая. Тетрациклиновые зубы: зубы ярко-желтого цвета интенсивно флюорисцируют в УФ-облучении. Зубы Гетчинсона.' ; document.getElementById('diagnoz').value = 'гипоплазия эмали К00.40 (МКБ-10)'">гипоплазия эмали</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('jaloby').value = 'На косметический дефект' ; document.getElementById('obekt').value = '' ; document.getElementById('diagnoz').value = 'гиперплазия эмали'">гиперплазия эмали</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('jaloby').value = 'На чувствительность от химических и температурных раздражителей в области ... зубов' ; document.getElementById('obekt').value = 'Твердые ткани зуба без изменения целостности, зондирование поверхности болезненно, реакция на температурные раздражители проходит сразу после устранения причины' ; document.getElementById('diagnoz').value = 'гиперестезия'">гиперестезия</a></li>
               </ul>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В jqery изменить место поиска

с

```
// Loop through the comment list
        $("nav ul li").each(function(){
```

на 
 `$(".1page-sidebar>li").each(function(){`

Comment: Если в поиске выбирается где именно нужно выполнить поиск то нужно передавать данные с названием блока где осуществляется поиск и тогда в js через переменную подставить нужно блок.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Руслан, но написал так как Вы и подсказали он перестал работать почемуто. В консоле тоже нету сообщений об ошибках ...Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать был бы очень благодарен !

Comment: Значит вы не правильно пишете селектор, покажите кусок кода со структурой. Запись .1page-sidebar>li означает, что искать в элементе с классом 1page-sidebar и только в li лежащих в нем. Т.е. если у Вас блок .1page-sidebar в нем ul и потом li то он искать не будет. в чем у вас лежат li конкретно и я смогу написать. На codepen можно написать $(".liveSearchBar li") и будет работать но можно и  $(".liveSearchBar>li") т.к. liveSearchBar это класс ul

Comment: Скорее всего да пишу неправильно. Приведу кусок кода в вопросе.

Comment: кстати меню тоже состоит из этих же элементов только там просто page-sidebar

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь Руслан ! написал так  $(" .1page-sidebar>ul>li").each(function() и всё сработало ! От души благодарен Вам !